# Setting URL params in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, url, typescript, parameters

I'm using following code:

```
this.router.navigate(['/app/chart', {chartColor: this.color, chartWidth: this.width}]);
```

And it sets my URL on:

```
http://localhost/app/chart;chartColor=blue;chartWidth=600
```

And it's fine. **But** when I call that function (which sends the variables to the URL) my component is **being reloaded**. And I dont really want it.

### I just want to send variables to the URL

**Is there any other, better way to achieve it?**

Comment: You're navigating from a component to another using `router.navigate` so you should expect the component to reload. Do you need to pass your params through URL ?

Comment: @YounesM Nope, I just need to send it to the URL of the same component. I want to make user able to just paste this URL and the chart in this component will have set width to `600` and will be `blue`. So the user doesnt have to do it by himself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know angular2 good enough but with angular "1" I use the following:

first i get the "base url" (protocol + hostname)

```
Tbaseurl = location.protocol + "//" + location.host+'/';
```

Then I add "variable" to my url by

```
urlVar = "?chartColor=blue&chartWidth=600"
```

and finally I write the string (url) to the browser's history:

```
window.history.pushState('name', '', Tbaseurl + urlVar);
```

this saves the url to the user's browser history (so if they want to go a page back they can do that) and it updates the url without needing to refresh the page

again, I can't really give you the answer because I don't know angular2 good enough to help you, but I hope this provides enough information to help you solve your problem

Comment: Thanks I will try it!

Comment: @henrythiuerryt had any luck with it ?